# Cannot update Eclipse WTP, Conflicting & Unsatisfied dependencies on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, websphere-liberty, eclipse-juno, eclipse-wtp

I tried to install/update `WTP` on `Eclipse Juno SR2` using `install new software` menu option, But unable to do because of the following errors,

```
 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: JAX-WS Tools SDK 1.2.0.v201204151854-44-90NCHNCDLLUuYbbV5cIkz-a69OdKTaLrU6UqY (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws_sdk.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v201204151854-44-90NCHNCDLLUuYbbV5cIkz-a69OdKTaLrU6UqY)
  Software being installed: JAX-WS Tools SDK 1.2.1.v201301072322-448a90NCHQC9KRWnSadV-_Nlyb19OdKTcLlRBVpX (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws_sdk.feature.feature.group 1.2.1.v201301072322-448a90NCHQC9KRWnSadV-_Nlyb19OdKTcLlRBVpX)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    JAX-WS Tools Developer Guide 1.1.100.v201301072322 (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.isv 1.1.100.v201301072322)
    JAX-WS Tools Developer Guide 1.1.0.v201104031551 (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.isv 1.1.0.v201104031551)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JAX-WS Tools SDK 1.2.0.v201204151854-44-90NCHNCDLLUuYbbV5cIkz-a69OdKTaLrU6UqY (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws_sdk.feature.feature.group 1.2.0.v201204151854-44-90NCHNCDLLUuYbbV5cIkz-a69OdKTaLrU6UqY)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.isv [1.1.0.v201104031551]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: JAX-WS Tools SDK 1.2.1.v201301072322-448a90NCHQC9KRWnSadV-_Nlyb19OdKTcLlRBVpX (org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws_sdk.feature.feature.group 1.2.1.v201301072322-448a90NCHQC9KRWnSadV-_Nlyb19OdKTcLlRBVpX)
    To: org.eclipse.jst.ws.jaxws.doc.isv [1.1.100.v201301072322]
```

URI used : `http://download.eclipse.org/webtools/repository/juno`

I am updating `WTP` on `Eclipse` to install `WAS Liberty Profile`, When I tried to install `WAS Liberty profile` following error occured,

```
    Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Profile Tools 8.5.5040.v20141119_2034 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.server.tools.feature.group 8.5.5040.v20141119_2034)
  Missing requirement: com.ibm.wdt.preferences 1.0.1.v20141119_2034 requires 'bundle org.eclipse.wst.web [1.1.700,2.0.0)' but it could not be found


    Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: Configuration for WebSphere® Application Server Developer Tools for Eclipse 1.0.1.v20141119_2034 (com.ibm.wdt.preferences.feature.feature.group 1.0.1.v20141119_2034)
        To: com.ibm.wdt.preferences [1.0.1.v20141119_2034]
      Cannot satisfy dependency:
        From: WebSphere® Application Server Liberty Profile Tools 8.5.5040.v20141119_2034 (com.ibm.websphere.wdt.server.tools.feature.group 8.5.5040.v20141119_2034)
        To: com.ibm.wdt.preferences.feature.feature.group [1.0.1.v20141119_2034]
```

Environment Details:

Eclipse version: Juno Service Release 2 
Eclipse Build id: 20130225-0426 
JDK used: jdk1.6.0_35

Answer (score 0):

You need **both** the WTP repository and the matching simultaneous release repository, as found at https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F . The simultaneous release repository is the more important of the two most of the time. It actually looks like the Liberty tools you're installing were intended for *Kepler*, and you can't do an in-place upgrade from Juno to Kepler.

Comment: I have downloaded WLP plugin from the following link, 
https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/websphere/wasdev/downloads/wdt/8.5.5/wdt-update-site_8.5.5.2.iFix.6.v20151126_2246.zip
Wherein the above link was marked up in the following page,
https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/#asset/tools-WebSphere_Developer_Tools_for_Eclipse_Juno